# How to push Avro event to Memsql

Tags: apache-kafka, real-time, avro, singlestore

I am working on POC to implement real time analytics where we have following components.

1. **Confluent Kafka** : Which gets events from third party services in Avro format (Event contains many fields up to 40). We are also using Kafka-Registry to deal with different kind of event formats.

I am trying to use MemSQL for analytics for which I have to push events to memsql table in specific format.

I have gone through memsql website , blogs etc but most of them are suggesting to use Spark memsql connector in which you can transform data which we are getting from confluent Kafka.

I have few questions.

1. If I use simple Java/Go application in place of Spark.
2. Is there any utility provided by Confluent Kafka and memsql

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using MemSQL Pipelines.  https://docs.memsql.com/memsql-pipelines/v6.0/kafka-pipeline-quickstart/
In current versions of MemSQL, you'll need to set up a transform, which will be a small golang or python script which reads in the avro and outputs TSV.  Instructions on how to do that is here https://docs.memsql.com/memsql-pipelines/v6.0/transforms/, but the tldr is, you need a script which does

`while True:
        record_size = read_an_8_byte_int_from_stdin()
        avro_record = stdin.read(record_size)
        stdout.write(AvroToTSV(avro_record))`

Stay tuned for native Avro support in MemSQL.

Comment: i dont understand the question?